# data-src could not load the image

Tags: html, angular

I was trying to show case a image in slide show using data-src tag of html 5. I don't know why it is not able to retrieve the image from the specified src path.
Below is my html code -

```html
<section class="slider_area row m0">
            <div class="slider_inner">
                <div data-thumb="./assets/images/slider-1.jpg" data-src="./assets/images/slider-1.jpg">
                    <div class="camera_caption">
                       <div class="container">
                            <h5 class=" wow fadeInUp animated">Welcome to our</h5>
                            <h3 class=" wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-delay="0.5s">RE THINK. RE DESIGN. RE BUILD</h3>
                            <p class=" wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-delay="0.8s">Our team of professionals will help you turn your dream home or flat into a reality fast. The Love Boat promises something for everyone. Now the world don't move to the beat of just one</p>
                            <a class=" wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-delay="1s" href="#">Read More</a>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-thumb="./assets/images/slider-2.jpg" data-src="./assets/images/slider-2.jpg">
                    <div class="camera_caption">
                       <div class="container">
                            <h5 class=" wow fadeInUp animated">Welcome to our</h5>
                            <h3 class=" wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-delay="0.5s">CLEAN ,MODERN, MULTIPURPOSE WEBSITE</h3>
                            <p class=" wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-delay="0.8s">Our team of professionals will help you turn your dream home or flat into a reality fast. The Love Boat promises something for everyone. Now the world don't move to the beat of just one</p>
                            <a class=" wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-delay="1s" href="#">Read More</a>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- End Slider area -->
```

Now look at my project structure where my image is present.

[image]

All my slider images are inside the images directory.

Please help

Comment: data-src does nothing by default. Show us your javascript

Comment: Hi @EriksKlotins data-src is a HTML tag. I  haven'y write any JS for the mentioned tag

Comment: data-src is not a tag. It is an attribute for a tag. Look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes
Data attributes are used to pass data between markup (html) and javascript.

Comment: @EriksKlotins \yes it's my mistake. It's an attribute of html tag

Comment: Your code looks like part of a jQuery or other plugin. Check the site where you got the code and include the required js files.